# User Help Document for Software (chm, html and hyperlink from application)

Tags: html, chm

I have an application, and now it's the time to write the user help document.  I need at least 3 features:

1. An offline UserHelp.chm;
2. An online version index.html;
3. Clicking "help" on any winform can guide the user to a specified help page.

So what kind of tools (HTML workshop?) are perfect for my project, and how to do? I appreciate if you can give me some general guidelines.

Comment: What's this have to do with C# or .NET?

Comment: I assume winform is .NET. Otherwise it would be a winapi or GDI form :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For requirement #1 and #2, I recommend you to use [SandCastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/).  It can generate chm file as well as ASP.NET pages.  Most importantly, this project is still active and maintained by Microsoft.

For requirement #3, you can google "context sensitive help winform".  You should be able to find a lot of references.  Here is [one of them from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ContextHelpMadeEasy.aspx#handlingHelpButton)

Comment: @Harvey, I'm using SandCastle for the Developers' TechAPI Help document.  Is it okay or easy to use for the User's document?

Comment: @Peter, I misread your question. I thought you are creating a API help. Perhaps, it's because this is how my company works.  Developers are responsible for API help and tech writer is responsible for user help :).  Anyway, SandCastle allows you to write conceptual content. It's very primitive and not much different from HTML workshop. The tech writer in our company likes to use framemaker, to generate chm, pdf and web pages.

Comment: @Harvey, thanks for your reply. I have used SandCastle for API Help, which requires the developers to put the XML-style comments for all classes and functions...  The question is, if I use SandCastle (Conceptual Content) for User Document, then the Tech Writer has to change the source code?

Comment: @Harvey, I also check ContextHelpMadeEasy, and I found that I have inherit all built-in Controls, such as Panel to PanelEx, in order to use the Context Help.  Since I have almost finished my apps, it's a nightmare to do this.   Or did I misunderstand that article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ContextHelpMadeEasy.aspx)?

Comment: @Peter You write XML files for conceptual content.  It's not inside your code.  It's in a separate XML file.  The tech writer may not like it though.  The tech writer may want HTML.  That one is doing something fancy.  I would suggest just use HelpProvider amd Help class from .NET framework.  Try this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/HelpIntegrationInDotNet.aspx

Comment: @Harvey, I found there is a big problem with the chm file: it does not support Unicode/UTF-8, which means multi-language Index or Keyword is impossible.  I'm giving up.  But I really don't know which Help system to use.

Answer (score 0):

If it must not be free of charge, I heard good things about Help & Manual: http://www.ec-software.com/

Helpware is another wellknown vendor: http://www.helpware.net/

Comment: I checked H&M, it seems that it's not free :-)

Comment: You did not mention free in your requirements.

Comment: Help & Manual is a great product, you can generate .CHM, .PDF and HTML from the same source. H&M is a GUI tool of course, but also has command-line option for batch processing of repetitive steps. Worth every cent.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Helpinator](http://www.helpinator.com), it's good too, but less expensive and has free edition.

Comment: it seems there are several features missing from the free version of Helpinator: http://www.helpinator.com/upgradetopro.html